# Python: Parse and Print Text File Line by Line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following question. How can I print an output file line by line. A simple example that i can think is the following. Any idea?

```
import codecs
output=codecs.open('output.txt','w', encoding='UTF-8')
for i in range(5):
   output.writelines(str(i)+'\n')
output.close()
```

I import `codecs` because maybe the input can be something else and not just the value `i`.

I take the following result:

```
01234
```

instead of:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: `cat output.txt == '0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n'`

Comment: @JakobBowyer sorry i did not catch you!

Comment: If I `cat` the contents of output thats what I get

Comment: writelines() does not add line separators.

Comment: Ref http://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/lib/bltin-file-objects.html

Comment: `codecs.open()` in unnecessary in Python 3; you can specify the encoding in a call to the builtin `open()`.

Comment: @Wooble: And even on Python 2 (as long as it's 2.6+), you're better off using `io.open` over `codecs.open`; the former is a backport of the Python 3 `io.open` (which is itself the built-in plain `open` on Python 3), and is both more efficient (it's mostly implemented in terms of C extension types, while `codecs.open` is mostly Python-level functions and classes) and more correct (`codecs.open` has all sorts of bugs, especially when opening in `+` modes, that `io.open` lacks; many never got fixed even in the Py3 timeframe since `io.open` worked better anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code *does* output newlines. Check that your editor recognizes `\n` newlines. However, it does so by accident. `writelines` expects a sequence of lines:

```
with open('output.txt','w', encoding='UTF-8') as output:
  output.writelines(str(i)+'\n' for i in range(5))
```

Comment: i do not know how to check if '\n' recognized by the compiler. i test in python 3.1 IDLE

Comment: The file is automatically closed once the control flow moves out of the [`with` statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `write` instead of `writelines`.

> writelines(sequence_of_strings) -> None.  Write the strings to the
>   file.
>
> Note that newlines are not added.  The sequence can be any iterable
>   object producing strings. This is equivalent to calling write() for
>   each string.

On the other hand:

> write(str) -> None.  Write string str to file.
>
> Note that due to buffering, flush() or close() may be needed before
>   the file on disk reflects the data written.

Comment: it is the same also with write()

Comment: @indiag Yes, `writelines` work the same way (sorry I didn't check before posting). However, the way your code is written you should use `write`, because you pass a string to it. The code should work fine, though.